# Vector of objects without a default constructor and iterator

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am learning to use C++ vectors, and I can't quite understand the output of the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Custom {
public:
    int v;

    Custom() = delete;

    explicit Custom(int v) : v{v} {};

    Custom(const Custom &) : v{4} {

    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Custom &th) {
        os << "V is " << th.v << endl;
        return os;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<Custom> c(2, Custom(3));
    c[0].v = 5;

    for (auto i: c) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

}
```

I expected it to produce the output

```
V is 5
V is 4
```

But instead it produces

```
V is 4

V is 4
```

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks.

Comment: Change `for (auto i: c)` to `for (auto &i: c)`

Comment: yes, this is it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This range based loop is making copies:

```
for (auto i: c) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

And the copy constructor initializes `v` to `4` (and does not make a copy):

```
Custom(const Custom &) : v{4} {

}
```

You can either implement a proper copy constructor or use references in the loop to get the desired output:

```
for (const auto& i: c) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

I would suggest to do both, because this copy constructor is not doing a copy by any means. The compiler generated copy constructor should be fine:

```
Custom(const Custom &) = default;
```

---

PS: The fact that `Custom` has a deleted default constructor is not really relevant for the posted code. Nowhere in the code a `Custom` is default constructed. Also there is no iterator in your code. In the range based loop `i` is a copy/reference of the elements in the vector, it is not an iterator.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question, I didn't realize that the loop was making copies!

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote:

```
for (auto i: c) //this uses copy constructor to copy initialize each element one by one from the vector
{

}
```

In the above snippet, each individual element of the vector is used to **copy initiaize** a temporary object named `i` while iterating through the vector. And since you have the `v{4}` in the **constructor initializer list** of the copy constructor you get the mentioned output.

To solve this you should replace: `auto i: c` with `auto &i: c` or `const auto &i: c` as shown below:

```
for (const auto &i: c) 
{
   cout << i << endl;
}
```

Now the elements of the vector are **not copied** into `i`. Instead they are references to the object themselves and so you'll get your expected output.